# sql file exported with PhpMyAdmin contains error message

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to export database through PhpMyAdmin tool. Exported file successfully uploads to machine but inside file it ends with error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>503 Service Unavailable</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Service Unavailable</h1>
        <p>The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: phpmyadmin export error]

I understand, it doesn't look like some limitation in configs but I have 2 assumptions:

- there some limit on file size for export
- there some timeout for request

Currently, I don't have access to the server, so I can't check config for PhpMyAdmin.
Perhaps, someone know exactly what cause that problem and which config responsible for it (if problem there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to Cpanel or the plesk server, you can change the configuration from there.